# run non web java application on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a simple Java application that I need to be running at all time (also to start automatically on server restart).
I have thought on a service wrapper, but the Windows version is paid.
Is there a way that I can configure Tomcat to run a specific class from a project automatically or any other solution that could give the same result?

Comment: Is a simple autostart not enough?

Comment: What kind of program is it? Does it have UI etc? othewise you can just create a tomcat contextListner or a servlet and in the the init method you can start your program.

Comment: There is no UI. The application just sends a POST request every 10 minutes and parses the result. 
One important thing is that I also need to keep check on the log output (System.out)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think  your need is to have an application (whatever web or non web) that starts with tomcat at the same time.

Well, you need to have a simple web application that registers a listener (that listens to the application start event i.e. tomcat start event) and launches your class.

It's very simple in your web.xml you declare a listener like this :

```
<listener>
        <description>application startup and shutdown events</description>
        <display-name>ApplicationListener</display-name>
        <listener-class>com.myapp.server.config.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And in you ApplicationListener class you implement ServletContextListener interface. Here is an example :

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;



/**
 * Class to listen for application startup and shutdown
 * 
 * @author HBR
 * 
 */
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        logger.info("class : context destroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        ServletContext context = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        ///// HERE You launch your class
        logger.info("myapp : context Initialized");
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google shows a bunch of options:

- [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) (likely the one mentioned)
- [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) (Based on JSW and designed to be largely compatible)
- [Windows Service Wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/simple-service-wrapper/) (Any app as a service, Windows only)
- [Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) (the one Tomcat uses)

Finally if you want it in Tomcat (as part of a web app) then something like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on:

1. http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp
2. http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html

Both will help you to run java application as a service. 
If however you want to run couple your application with tomcat you can implement your own simple web application that runs your application. You can use either

1. servlet that starts on server startup (configure this in web.xml)
2. HTTP filter
3. ServletContextListener.